# AngularJS - Updating variable every second

Tags: angularjs, updates

What is the best way to update a variable every second?

What I want is that when the user clicks on a button, it will make variable x be updated (added 1, for example) every second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Angular's interval Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interval)

`Angular's wrapper for window.setInterval. The fn function is executed every delay milliseconds.`